# How to convert higher order Bézier curves to piecewise cubic Bézier curves

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

Is it possible to convert higher order Bézier curves to piecewise cubic Bézier curves in Inkscape?

Comment: As far as I know and according to a brief search, neither Inkscape nor any other graphics program does supports Bézier curves of orders higher than three (cubic) at all. What makes you think that Inkscape could be able to do this? And why are you interested in this feature?

Comment: jThis question could be better suited to [computer graphics.SE](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-are-the-graphics-libraries-available-for-use-in-the-python-ubuntu-ecosystem). @Wrzlprmft This kond of thing happens in data fitting and engineering applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look over this question on StackOverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419726/simplify-high-order-bezier-curve

Now... as far as supporting higher-order curves in inkscape, Wrzlprmft is right. SVG path data only has commands for orders of the 2nd and 3rd order.

You could, in theory, build a path effect with python that *pretends* that a set of points are all control points of a single curve, then go through the trouble of sub-dividing that curve into cubic and quadratic curves.

http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Script_extensions

I would encourage you to crack open Inkscape to view the path effect python files that already exist to use as guidance. And be prepared to be frustrated. It's a long road.